# jQuery gear rotation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with gear rotation on my website http://www.whirlware.biz

I made what I want here http://jsfiddle.net/kDSqB/112/ and it works, but I don't now why it don't works on my website. Can you help me please?

```
<div id="cog"><img src="http://pngicon.ru//data/media/3/2_43.png"/></div>
```

```
var $cog = $('#cog'),
    $body = $(document.body),
    bodyHeight = $body.height();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $cog.css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)'
    });
});
```

Comment: Open the console, everything in red are errors.

Comment: Like @adeneo said, open up your console, check what the errors are and see if you can't find a solution when searching for those errors. If you still can't figure it out, report back with the errors and we can go from there.

Comment: TypeError: $body.height is not a function
 

bodyHeight = $body.height();

I don`t know how to fix it because in jsfiddle this function works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your jQuery script in a DOMready function:

```
jQuery(function($){

    // put all your code above here    

});
```

It works your jsFiddle because the script there is set to run `onDomready`. Note the option under which framework to load.

On a side note `$(document.body)` is the same as `$('body')`.